# -Python- WordSearch: Placing words to handle overlap properly

Tags: python, arrays, loops, wordsearch

I have been working on a program that will run from command line that reads a file with words in it, and then generate a WordSearch game from those words.

I have defined several functions, but the one I am having the issue with is the word_place function. This function is supposed to take my grid or 2D array that is originally filled with periods:

```
width = 20
height = 20
grid = [['.' for i in range(0,width)] for j in range(0,height)]
```

And places the words randomly either backwards or forwards, vertically, horizontally, or diagonally, and in a random spot as long as it fits the width and height of the puzzle.

```
def word_place(word,grid):
global width, height

word = random.choice([word,word[::-1]])

direction = random.choice([[1,0],[0,1],[1,1]])
xsize = width if direction[0] == 0 else width - len(word)
ysize = height if direction[1] == 0 else height - len(word)

x = random.randrange(0,xsize)
y = random.randrange(0,ysize)

for i in range(0,len(word)):
    grid[y + direction[1]*i][x + direction[0]*i] = word[i]

return grid
```

As you can probably see though, if the words happen to intersect, whichever word was placed last will write over the character of the word it intersects.

What I want the program to do is to check each "coordinate" of my 2D array.

For example, say the first letter of the word happens to be at `grid[5][8]`, it should check and see if there is a period in that position. If so then it will check the next square and so on.

Basically if the letter of the word I'm trying to place is `==` to a `.` or whatever letter is already in the index then it is okay to place, otherwise it should scrap that, and give the word a new starting coordinate and try again.

Sorry if this is long or unclear.. let me know if you need more information!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a place for a `for-else` construct:

```
while True:
    x = random.randrange(0,xsize)
    y = random.randrange(0,ysize)

    for i in range(0,len(word)):
        if grid[y + direction[1]*i][x + direction[0]*i] not in ['.',word[i]]:
            break
    else:
        break
for i in range(0,len(word)):
    grid[y + direction[1]*i][x + direction[0]*i] = word[i]
```

this continues changing `x` and `y` until the initial for loop runs without breaking. The first for loop will break any time that a value in the grid is not either a free space or the letter that it would need to be (`word[i]`).

Comment: I implemented this and the program ran infinitely. I think it got stuck in that loop. After interrupting the program using a KeyboardInterrupt, the grid generated looking fine but I got some errors.

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wordsearchop.py", line 56, in <module>
    main()
  File "wordsearchop.py", line 53, in main
    grid = word_place(word,grid)
  File "wordsearchop.py", line 23, in word_place
    y = random.randrange(0,yspace)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\random.py", line 194, in randrange
    return istart + self._randbelow(width)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\random.py", line 230, in _randbelow
    r = getrandbits(k)          # 0 <= r < 2**k
KeyboardInterrupt`

Comment: so the word got inserted still? or no? because if it did then theres something funky going on. if not, maybe a fail-safe is needed for certain amount of iterations

Comment: Nevermind, It worked just fine for some reason after running it again a few times. Thank you!

Comment: I would suggest a failsafe to only run a certain amount of times, so instead of doing `while True` have a counter and increment it every time and change to `while counter < someMaxValue`

Answer (score 0):

you could just do a first pass testing that all spaces are available and record the indexes. If it was free then insert the values. If the value of the grid matches the character that will be places there, then it is still fine.

If you test while you insert, you will still have to record where you have inserted as you will have to backtrack to replace the partial word with '.'s